# Error in dbSendQuery - Shiny R

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny

I am trying to add `Username`, `Password` and `Email` to the table `users` in `db` database. Any idea why this `dbSendQuery` is not working.
The error is : `Error in rsqlite_send_query: near "username": syntax error`

```
Username <- isolate(input$uname)
Password <- isolate(input$pswd)
Email <- isolate(input$email)
db <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
query <- sprintf({"INSERT INTO users username=%s and password=%s and email=%s"},Username, Password, Email, serialize=F)
RSQLite::dbSendQuery(db,query) 
RSQLite::dbDisconnect(db)
```

Other attempts:

```
1: query <- sprintf({"INSERT INTO users %s and %s and %s"},Username, Password, Email, serialize=F)
2: query <- sprintf("insert into users (username, password, email) values (%s,%s,%s)", Username, Password, Email)
3: dbSendQuery(db,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('Username','Password','Email');")
4: dbSendQuery(db,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",Username, Password, Email)
5: query<-paste("insert into users (username, password, email) values (",Username,",",Password,",",Email,")")
```

Comment: The `Username` variable may be blank. Try something like `str(query)` immediately after assigning it to see what it contains.

Comment: I wish I knew why I got a negative vote!

Comment: The negative vote was not from me, it is frustrating when no feedback is given. What did the `str(query)` reveal?

Comment: @awchisholm, I did not mean that it was from you.Anyway, No blank, the query is correct

Comment: In your `ui.r`, does `input$uname` default to a value? Probably worth trying to post a minimal example so others can recreate it.

Comment: I edited my question @awchisholm. Also, I have no defult value

Comment: I think `Username` is blank the first time the `isolate()` function is called. Try `str(Username)` - what does the console output show?

Comment: @awchisholm, the output is chr "name"

Comment: You need to post a complete example to allow progress to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
dbSendQuery(db, sprintf({"INSERT INTO users (username,password,email) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')"},Username, Password,Email))
RSQLite::dbDisconnect(db)
```